# Is there a way through DPI firewall?

Tags: censorship, firewall

Within a corporate network I'm sitting behind a DPI (deep packet inspection) firewall. Is there any way to break out?
I don't know the manufacturer of the firewall - all I know is, that it work with DPI and is also capable to look inside of encrypted (HTTPS) traffic.

Answer (score 2):

You might look at the pluggable transports like [obfsproxy](https://www.torproject.org/projects/obfsproxy.html.en) which is designed with DPI in mind. You might also try using a [bridge relay](https://www.torproject.org/docs/bridges) rather than the regular 9 directory authority servers. These are the two typical ways firewalls can be bypassed that I know of.

Comment: If it's actually doing DPI to block Tor a Bridge Relay won't help.

Comment: This is likely true, it all depends on the configuration of the firewall you are trying to circumvent. The only case where a bridge relay would help is if the ip addresses of known exit nodes are being blocked. Firewall configurations can vary greatly, so you will probably need to try multiple solutions to find what works.

Comment: A bridge relay + pluggable transport (e.g. obfs4proxy) works through DPI looking for the tor applicazion pattern.